# ActiveRecord Cannot save a record: "zero-length delimited identifier"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on a project that allows users to rate recipes. I made a simple join table (RecipeRating) that User and Recipe both share, but ActiveRecord is having trouble saving.

```
@rating = @user.recipe_ratings.where(:recipe_id => @recipe.id).first
@rating.rating = params[:rating]
@rating.save
```

Yields:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#rate_recipe
PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...013-08-07 14:28:39.965953' WHERE "recipe_ratings"."" IS NULL
                                                             ^
: UPDATE "recipe_ratings" SET "rating" = 3, "updated_at" = '2013-08-07 14:28:39.965953' WHERE "recipe_ratings"."" IS NULL
```

Clearly the error is caused by `WHERE "recipe_ratings"."" IS NULL`  but what is causing this and how do I fix it? For reference, it's having no trouble creating or finding ratings (which are saved as expected in my db), it just can't update them.

For reference:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :recipe_ratings
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :recipe_ratings
end

class RecipeRating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :comment, :rating, :user, :recipe#, :user_id, :recipe_id
end
```

Comment: Try this, just in case: `@rating = @user.recipe_ratings.find_by_recipe_id(@recipe.id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by giving the RecipeRating table its own primary key.

Comment: Why didn't you have an id to begin with?